# I was trying to migrate my app code from jcenter to mavenCentral in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jcenter, maven-central

I was trying to migrate my app code from jcenter to mavenCentral but when I build the output then this error shown I searched the google and youtube but I didn't get any solution for this error in android studio.

Error -

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.3.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find link.fls:swipestack:0.3.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.mindorks.android:placeholderview:1.0.3.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find :unspecified:.
     Required by:
         project :app > id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0
   > Could not find com.daasuu:EasingInterpolator:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.2.0

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

Build.gradle -

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }


}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Build.gradle(app) -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sunnwy.firedate"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.curioustechizen.android-ago:library:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.0.1'
    implementation "com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:2.3.2"
    implementation 'link.fls:swipestack:0.3.0'
    implementation 'com.mindorks.android:placeholderview:1.0.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.mindorks.android:placeholderview-compiler:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.1.5'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.ss.bannerslider:bannerslider:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.6'
    implementation 'com.sackcentury:shinebutton:0.2.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If anybody know how to solve the problem pls tell me

Comment: Do the libraries exist on Maven Central?

Comment: No, I don't think that libraries exist on maven central but I didn't have any choice because jcenter is shutdown

Comment: According to https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown, they decided to make it read-only indefinitely. So, you can still rely on JCenter, but you'll never get updated versions of the libraries from JCenter. You'll probably need to look at each library and see if they have started to upload to other repositories (e.g., Maven Central), and what versions are available in that new repository.

Comment: Here's a quote from that blog: "_Packages that are hosted on JCenter will need to find an alternative repository to provide updates after March 31 2021. Many packages will likely migrate to Maven Central, but some packages may not migrate at all and some may only publish new versions. Abandoned projects could change their coordinates as other maintainers take over. This means the transition from JCenter to another repository will be more difficult than simply using a different repository URL_".